# Issue with the optional chaining operator "?." after updating to Angular 17

Tags: angular, typescript

Previously, I was on Angular `13`, my component was working correctly! I have since upgraded to other versions of Angular, currently at version `16`. And I wanted to fix a `warning` because I had a syntax issue.

```
src/app/.../annexes.component.html:6:65 - warning NG8107: The left side of this optional chain 
operation does not include 'null' or 'undefined' in its type, therefore the '?.' 
operator can be replaced with the '.' operator.     

 <h2 *ngIf="annexeDetails">{{ annexeDetails?.TITRE }} - {{ id }}</h2>  

src/app/.../annexes.component.ts:15:16
templateUrl: './annexes.component.html',
                      ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
Error occurs in the template of component AnnexesComponent.
```

And

```
Warning: src/app/.../corporate-actions-details-confirm-modal/corporate-actions-details-confirm-modal.component.html:32:60 - 

warning NG8107: The left side of this optional chain operation does not include 'null' 
or 'undefined' in its type, therefore the '?.' operator can be replaced with the '.' operator.      

32 - {{ ostDetail?.LIMITEDATE | date: "d MMMM y" }}.
                                                              ~~~~~~~~~~

src/app/.../corporate-actions-details-confirm-modal/corporate-actions-details-confirm-modal.component.ts:14:16
14   templateUrl: './corporate-actions-details-confirm-modal.component.html',
```

I replaced

```
<h2 *ngIf="annexeDetails">{{ annexeDetails?.TITRE }} - {{ id }}</h2>
```

With

```
<h2 *ngIf="annexeDetails">{{ annexeDetails.TITRE }} - {{ id }}</h2>
```

And the second

```
{{ ostDetail?.LIMITEDATE | date: "d MMMM y" }}
```

With

```
{{ ostDetail.LIMITEDATE | date: "d MMMM y" }}
```

But it doesn't work with these new modifications, because `ostDetail` can be `null` or `undefined`.

I don't know how to solve this issue. I will have to go back to version `13`?

Comment: Do you have `ostDetail!` (with exclamation mark) somewhere in your code?

Comment: This warning is explained in the [Angular Docs](https://angular.io/extended-diagnostics/NG8107)

Comment: Hello Tortila, Yes on this component. `export class CorporateActionsDetailsConfirmModalComponent implements OnInit, OnDestroy {
  private unsubscribe$ = new Subject<void>();

  @Input() ostDetail!: Ost;` why?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As you confirmed in comments, you have `@Input() ostDetail!: Ost;` in your template code.

Exclamation mark is [non-null assertion operator](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-2-0.html#non-null-assertion-operator). You are telling the compiler that you are providing non-null and non-undefined value. But are you?

I assume you have something like `[ostDetail]="ostDetail$ | async"` in your parent component. In this case `ostDetail` can be null until observable `ostDetail$` produces a value. You can fix it by using `*ngIf` or using `Ost | null` type.

I encourage you to use [strict mode](https://angular.io/guide/strict-mode) in Angular. It might be annoying at first, but it really pays you off.

Comment: As a bonus for now using Angular 16, you can add [required](https://angular.io/api/core/Input) option: `@Input({ required: true })`.

Comment: Thank you a lot, my problem is resolved.